# InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a GitHub project to a EC2 Instance using AWS CodeDeploy. After following 2 video tutorials an a bunch of Google answer, I'm still getting the following error:

```
2017-02-01 12:20:08 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1379)]: master 1379: Spawned child 1/1
2017-02-01 12:20:09 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1383)]: On Premises config file does not exist or not readable
2017-02-01 12:20:09 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1383)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Archives to retain is: 5}
2017-02-01 12:20:09 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(1383)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.
2017-02-01 12:20:09 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(1383)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile
```

I have two IAM:

- CodeDeployInstanceRole
- CodeDeployServiceRole

### CodeDeployInstanceRole for the EC2 Instance

**Policy Name**: AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:ListObjects"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Policy Name**: AutoScalingNotificationAccessRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:SendMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
            "sns:Publish"
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Trust Relationship

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

### CodeDeployServiceRole for CodeDeploy

**Policy Name**: AWSCodeDeployRole

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
        "autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
        "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat",
        "autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup",
        "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
        "autoscaling:EnableMetricsCollection",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribePolicies",
        "autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
        "autoscaling:DescribeNotificationConfigurations",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
        "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
        "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
        "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancers",
        "autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
        "autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction",
        "autoscaling:PutNotificationConfiguration",
        "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
        "autoscaling:DeleteAutoScalingGroup",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "tag:GetTags",
        "tag:GetResources",
        "sns:Publish",
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeInstanceHealth",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Trust Relationship

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

## EC2 Instance

I spin my own image that I have created based on Debian so I have NodeJS already installed. When I spin the new instance I also paste the following code in the `User data` text area to make sure CodeDeploy is installed.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

REGION=$(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/ | sed 's/[a-z]$//') &&

sudo apt-get update -y &&

sudo apt-get install -y python-pip &&

sudo apt-get install -y ruby &&

sudo apt-get install -y wget &&

cd /home/admin &&

wget https://aws-codedeploy-$REGION.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install &&

chmod +x ./install &&

sudo ./install auto &&

sudo apt-get remove -y wget &&

sudo service codedeploy-agent start
```

## Debugging

If I log in in the EC2 instance that I have create, and execute the following command:

```
echo $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)
```

I get the following response `CodeDeployInstanceRole`

When I then execute

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/CodeDeployInstanceRole
```

I get the following response

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2017-02-01T12:38:07Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "THE_KEY",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "SECRET",
  "Token" : "TOKEN",
  "Expiration" : "2017-02-01T19:08:43Z"
}
```

On GitHub I see that CodeDeploy never accesses my repo even when I select deployment using GitHub, I set the right repo name, and commit ID.

[image]

## Question

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that by default Debian doesn't have `curl` installed. Installing `curl` before making the curl request to get the region the server is running on was the missing part in the Bash script.

Comment: That's good that you find the solution. I am also facing the same issue, could you be so kind and share your steps so I can compare what I am missing. I am using CodeDeploy, BitBucket and AWS EC2 instance and following https://medium.com/@asoheili/one-click-deployment-to-aws-with-codedeploy-and-bitbucket-8550103207e

Comment: Sure, check what I wrote here: https://github.com/0x4447/0x4447-article-how-to-think-about-the-AWS-infrastructure/tree/master/09_CodeDeploy - I did dump all that I learned in that article. I hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 81):

I ran into the same issue. Briefly what caused the problem:

- Launch an instance WITHOUT any roles attached to it
- Then install a codedeploy-agent on that machine
- Only lastly attach an IAM role to the machine

Result: I get the error: `Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile`

**Solution**: restart the codedeploy agent. Use:

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
```

The error should be gone now!

Comment: I did the exact same thing and this fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me. I had not attached IAM while creating the instance. I added it later on. So this restart worked for me

Comment: How do you attach IAM role to a machine?

Comment: This fixed my issue. Plus seems like codedeploy-agent only looks for "appspec.yml" file and not "appspec.yaml"

Answer (score 25):

I was getting the "please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile". To check if your instance is launched without IAM profile go to AWS console -> your instance -> check in Description tab "IAM role" value, if it's empty then you have launched instance without IAM and here is what to do to solve the issue:

1. Go to IAM console -> Roles -> Create new role

   Select AWS Service -> EC2 -> Next: Permissions(don't change anything) -> Next: Tags -> Next: Review -> Give the name and click Create role.
2. Go to AWS EC2 console -> select instance -> Actions -> Instance settings -> Attach/replace IAM role -> Select IAM role you just created
3. Restart codedeploy agent: sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
4. Try to deploy again and it should work

Answer (score 3):

Detach the profile from EC2 and then attach it back (Actions -> Security). Finally restart the agent with

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
```

My case is slightly different from other answers. My profile looks correct and it has correct policy. And the EC2 is attached to the role - at least that what I see in AWS console.

The root cause is that the EC2 do not has a correct profile with it due to some regeneration of the same-name profile role. This can confirmed with `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info`

404 means something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The instance role permissions look good to me. But the IAM instance profile was added only at the first time when the instance was launched. Could you make sure the instances role had the right permissions before launching the instances?

Comment: Could you be so kind, and tell me how to do that? Or point to a link where it shows how to do that, so we can be sure that I'm checking the right way :)

Comment: When we launch an ec2 instance, we are asked to provide "IAM role" on page "Step 3: Configure Instance Details". The IAM role provided here  that I referred that might not have enough permission. Example settings are here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to restart the Code Deploy Agent:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart codedeploy-agent
```

Also, I had to rename my deployment spec from "appspec.yaml" to "appspec.yml", seems like the agent only looks for `.yml` extension -- btw I found this error after I looked into `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log` log file

```bash
$ tail /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
2023-05-27T08:08:35 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(8830)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Calling PutHostCommandComplete: "Code Error" 
2023-05-27T08:08:35 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(8830)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.6.0-49_rpm.
2023-05-27T08:08:35 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(8830)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.033923 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":5,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"The CodeDeploy agent did not find an AppSpec file within the unpacked revision directory at revision-relative path \\\"appspec.yml\\\". The revision was unpacked to directory \\\"/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f5518867-7740-4ce5-b65d-0931a6b26e66/d-THOQCJXLO/deployment-archive\\\", and the AppSpec file was expected but not found at path \\\"/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/f5518867-7740-4ce5-b65d-0931a6b26e66/d-THOQCJXLO/deployment-archive/appspec.yml\\\". Consult the AWS CodeDeploy Appspec documentation for more information at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html\",\"log\":\"\"}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in 2021 on Ubuntu 16.04

## Upgrade from Python 3.5.2 to 3.6

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/
with sudo ...

```sh
cd /opt
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.6.3.tgz
cd Python-3.6.3
./configure
apt-get install zlib1g-dev
make
make install
```

## Install latest version of aws cli v1

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html

```sh
cd ~
curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

## Modify Instance Metadata

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-metadata-options.html

```sh
aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options \
  --instance-id ${FOO_ID} \
  --http-tokens optional \
  --http-endpoint enabled
```

## Install the CodeDeploy agent for Ubuntu Server

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-ubuntu.html

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo apt-get install wget
cd /home/ubuntu
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

#### To view deployment log files on Amazon Linux, RHEL, and Ubuntu Server instances

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html

```sh
tail -f /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
tail -f /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs/codedeploy-agent-deployments.log
```